# Visual.VisualEdgeMode property can be set for derived class but not as a class member

Tags: c#, wpf

In the code below, my LineAliased and LineAntiAliased classes derive from DrawingVisual and I am able to use the "this" keyword to set the "VisualEdgeMode" property for each class. This works fine and I can draw the lines to the canvas as expected, with one line Aliased and one line AntiAliased.

However, in my Lines class I do not derive from DrawingVisual and instead create DrawingVisual members for the class.

The problem is that when I try and set the "VisualEdgeMode" property for these members I am getting the error "System.Windows.Media.Visual.VisualEdgeMode is inaccessible due to its protection level".

I'm pretty new and haven't been able to find a decent explanation elsewhere of what I am doing wrong and why this doesn't work.

**Visual.VisualEdgeMode property on MSDN**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualedgemode(v=vs.110).aspx

**DrawingVisual class on MSDN**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual(v=vs.110).aspx

THANK YOU!

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;

namespace CanvasTest
{
    public class LineAliased : DrawingVisual
    {
        public LineAliased()
        {
            this.VisualEdgeMode = EdgeMode.Aliased;
            DrawingContext dc = this.RenderOpen();
            dc.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), 1), new Point(100, 105), new Point(300, 105));
            dc.Close();
        }
    }

    public class LineAntiAliased : DrawingVisual
    {
        public LineAntiAliased()
        {
            this.VisualEdgeMode = EdgeMode.Unspecified;
            DrawingContext dc = this.RenderOpen();
            dc.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), 1), new Point(100, 100), new Point(300, 100));
            dc.Close();
        }
    }

    public class Lines
    {
        public DrawingVisual objDrawingVisualAliased = new DrawingVisual();
        public DrawingVisual objDrawingVisualAntiAliased = new DrawingVisual();

        public Lines()
        {
            // Next line gives following error.
            // System.Windows.Media.Visual.VisualEdgeMode is inaccessible due to its protection level.
            objDrawingVisualAliased.VisualEdgeMode = EdgeMode.Aliased;
            DrawingContext dc1 = objDrawingVisualAliased.RenderOpen();
            dc1.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), 1), new Point(100, 105), new Point(300, 105));
            dc1.Close();

            // Next line gives following error.
            // System.Windows.Media.Visual.VisualEdgeMode is inaccessible due to its protection level.
            objDrawingVisualAntiAliased.VisualEdgeMode = EdgeMode.Unspecified;
            DrawingContext dc2 = objDrawingVisualAntiAliased.RenderOpen();
            dc2.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), 1), new Point(100, 105), new Point(300, 105));
            dc2.Close();
        }
    }

    public class DrawingCanvas : Canvas
    {
        // This object is used to work with the Visuals belonging to the Canvas.
        private VisualCollection graphicsList;

        public DrawingCanvas()
        {
            graphicsList = new VisualCollection(this);
            graphicsList.Add(new LineAliased());
            graphicsList.Add(new LineAntiAliased());


            Lines lines = new Lines();
            graphicsList.Add(lines.objDrawingVisualAliased);
            graphicsList.Add(lines.objDrawingVisualAntiAliased);
        }

        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254.aspx#creating_overrides
        // Provide required overrides
        protected override int VisualChildrenCount  { get { return graphicsList.Count; } }
        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= graphicsList.Count) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); }
            return graphicsList[index];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx) member is accessible only within its class and by derived class instances.

Answer (score 0):

The `VisualEdgeMode` property is `protected` and is hence only accesible from methods of a derived class (or the defining class itself).

You may however call the static [RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.setedgemode.aspx) instead:

```
RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(objDrawingVisualAliased, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```